# usb 4 port rs232 hub, name of devices

Tags: serial, usb-hub

What if I use [this UBS to 4 RS232 Cable](https://www.conrad.at/de/usb-11-seriell-anschlusskabel-1x-usb-20-stecker-a-4x-d-sub-stecker-9pol-150-m-schwarz-digitus-989065.html?sc.ref=Cart) ? Will be the device names e.g /dev/ttyUSB0 - /dev/ttyUSB3 always the same for each RS232 connector ?

For example:

If I plug in the USB connector, the convertes will be given names. Will UART plug 1 always have the lowest number e.g. /dev/ttyUSB0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally yes. Every USB device designed with a bit of sanity will enumerate its endpoints in the same order every time, and Linux will assign them names in form of `ttyUSBx`, starting with 0.

Note that this will not be true if you e.g. plug another USB UART adapter first - it will get the name `ttyUSB0`, and numbers in names assigned to your cable will increase by one. It's also conceivable that some device names may become unavailable - for example, if you unplug the cable while a process is trying to read from `ttyUSB0`, the driver may not be able to remove it properly, so when you replug the cable, it will be assinged device names starting from `ttyUSB1`.

Comment: What If I use an udev rule instead ? Like `KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="<vendorid>", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="mydev"` ? Will that map `/dev/ttyUSB0` to ``/dev/mydev0` ? Of course this approach would limit me to a specific converter cable.

Comment: Yes, you can map device names using udev rules, but beware - mapping `ttyUSB0` to `mydev0` will only be reliable if the `ttyUSB0` name is assigned consistently in the first place. You will want to identify serial numbers of your UARTs and use `ATTRS{serial}=="XXXX"` in the rules.

Comment: I heard about the "udev" rules, but never tried to understand it.  So I took the liberty to add this name in the OP's title, hoping other interested udev newbies might visit this Q&A to learn new things.