# Identify which microphone is on which audio card using arecord

Tags: usb, audio, input-device, microphone

I'm using a Raspberry PI and on it I plugged two same USB microphones. I would like to be able to identify which USB microphone is on which audio card when I list devices with arecord:

```
arecord --list-devices
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: iTalk02_1 [iTalk-02], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: iTalk02 [iTalk-02], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I thought about using usb serial number but these devices doesn't provide any (or I don't know how to use well `lsusb -v`). But how to match results from `lsusb -v` command with `arecord --list-devices`?

I need either an identifier of the microphone or the number of the USB port.

OS information:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)
Release: 9.9
Codename: stretch
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks, Dylan

Comment: Hi @Dylan Delaporte, I have two USB sound cards.  I did the following: (1) Plug in #1 and arecord --list--, lsusb, (2) Plug in one more sound card, and did the same, (3) Note the IDs of the two sound cards.  Does this help? For now, no speaker or microphone is plugged.  I can add two speakers and two mikes to see what happens, if you like.

Comment: Ref 1 in my answer might also be helpful: "How to setup persistent device names on Raspberry Pi - Rolf Blijleven"
https://rolfblijleven.blogspot.com/2015/02/howto-persistent-device-names-on.html.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> How to identify which microphone on which USB sound card?

---

***Answer***

*update 2019nov06hkt1558*

> Finding the IDs of multiple USB sound cards, with microphones.  Also see Ref 1 on [How to setup persistent device names on Rpi](https://rolfblijleven.blogspot.com/2015/02/howto-persistent-device-names-on.html).

---

[image: usb sound card]

---

*I have two USB sound cards. This is how I identify them:*

> (1) Plug in one sound card - #1 and (a) $ arecord --list--, (b) $ lsusb,
>
> (2) Plug in one more sound card - #2 and repeat Step (1),
>
> (3) Note the IDs of #1 and #2 USB sound cards.

[image: sound card ids]

---

***References***

(1) [Arecord, Aplay - command-line sound recorder and player for ALSA soundcard driver](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord)

(2) [To use USB mini microphone on Raspbian - SunFounder](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=To_use_USB_mini_microphone_on_Raspbian)

(3) [How to set up persistent device names on Raspberry Pi - Rolf Blijleven](https://rolfblijleven.blogspot.com/2015/02/howto-persistent-device-names-on.html)

(4) [How to name / map devices on an USB to 4 RS232 cables / ports / hub, using udev rules? - Rpi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55985/usb-4-port-rs232-hub-name-of-devices)

(5) [AliExpress Ugreen USB External Sound Card - US$12](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32701486923.html?spm=2114.12010612.8148356.11.5b4d3f51ALwPZZ)

(6) [USB Sound Card Selection Guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976&p=1396404&hilit=ugreen%20usb%20sound%20card#p1396404)

(7) [MAX9812 Microphone Amplifier](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=233122&p=1427158&hilit=ugreen%20usb%20sound%20card#p1427187)

(8) [PAM8610 10W Stero Class-D Audio Power Amplifier With DC Volume Control](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8610.pdf)

---

*End of answer*