# Audio Jack Issue PI 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, audio

I have connected my external speaker to the audio jack that only is powered by an adapter. The audio seems not to be working for some reason. It tells me that there is no soundcards found.

Whenever I load the sound cards by doing `sudo lsmod | grep 2835` it returns the following:

[image]

So I then attempt to run `aplay -l` and it still shows me no soundcards found. I also ran the command `sudo amixer cset numid=3 1` and it changes it but nothing.

My version is shown below:
[image]

I also did force the audio to 3.5mm in the audio when running the command `sudo raspi-config`.

I have this flashed to my SD btw.

[image]

Is there something I can do to fix this issue?

Below shows my sound drive for my microphone and lists of items when I do `sudo dkms status` but nothing shows up when I do `aplay -l`:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you mean you are NOT using any original, genuine, unmodified, unhacked, Rpi os image, but something else?

Comment: It is not clear if the original buster is up to date.  Try "uname -a" and let us know if the linux version is 4.19.75... or later.

Comment: I apologize, fairly new to this. Yes, I am using the 4.19.75. Whenever I run the "uname -a" command this is what gets returned: Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux @tlfong01

Comment: Ah, let me see.  If your linux kernel is 4.19.75... dated TueSep24, then it is the most up to date.  The problem might be that your os image AIY Kits 2019-11-03, which is very new, which might not support Rpi4B or something.  To troubleshoot, I would suggest the following: (1) Forget the AIY project os image.  Just download/use the unmodified 2019sep26 or later image and see if you can play audio, say, use VLC media player to play mp3 files.

Comment: This is to make sure your Rpi built in audio output circuit (sort of "sound card", but no audio in) is working, or you are configuring the audio output correctly. This is not as simple as you think.  Many newbies actually get stuck just in using the 3.5mm jack speaker.

Comment: Another thing is that the 3.5mm jack is output only.  So I think you need to have an USB sound card to use a microphone. Please confirm if you do have an USB sound card to use microphone (and also speaker, if you like).  The following posts about USB sound cards might be useful: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105280/identify-which-microphone-is-on-which-audio-card-using-arecord, 
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105305/waveshare-wm8960-audio-sound-card-hat-installation-on-rpi-zero-w-problem

Comment: And please confirm if you are up to date at least with the following user guide and installation discussions: (1)
AIY [voice and video] Projects Documentation Release 2018-11-16 Google LLC Nov 14, 2019
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/aiyprojects/latest/aiyprojects.pdf

(2) AIY Kit Installation Problem,
https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/issues/645

Comment: @tlfong01 Is there a link where I can access the unmodified 2019sep26 or later image? Also I am not running the os image on a pi 4, I am running it on a pi 3 model b... would this make a difference? In regards to the sound cards for the microphone please see the modified post, there I posted a screenshot of the commands I ran to show the sound cards.

Comment: Hi @beloas, Ah let me see.  I am still confused.  You seem to have jump started to use the GG AIY os image WITHOUT any previous experience with the official Rpi os image.  I usually google "Rpi", "download" to find the official down load site.  Just now I visited their site and found the most up to date version is still 2019sep26. I would suggest to download the fullest version there, ie, NOT Lite or NOOBS. And if my guess of your situation is correct, I would suggest you to first download and play with the official image, ... I will answer your other questions later. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: Hi @tlfong01! Thank you so much for the help! Yes, I was following a tutorial on youtube and was provided with a link for the os image, which was not working with the audio for some reason. However, I went ahead and did exactly what you said and tested the audio and mic and ran some commands to configure them and I got it to work! Thank you so much you are a true life saver!

Comment: Hi @beloas, Oh my goodness, so you are really a very quick learner! Congrats! Now let us confirm what have you done so far, and what to do next. (1) So you have used buster sep26 to test Rpi3B's audio input and output devices (microphone on USB sound card, and speaker on USB sound card, or Rpi 3.5mm jack.  So this is your standard config to test or make sure Rpi audio input/output hardware and software is working OK.  (2) Next you can do what you like, say replace the official Rpi buster os image by your GG AIY os image and test again, perhaps again test if audio io is still working,  ... !:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101451/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-beloas).